# Не работает функция отсчета таймера

Tags: c#

Мне нужно в 2 lebl'а парсить минуты и секунды соответсвенно. Вот функция которую я сделал:

```
 public void StartTimer()//Функция запуска отсчета таймера
    {
        if(timer1.Enabled)
        {
            if (minutes <= 59&&minutes>=0)
            {
                minutes--;
                if (minutes < 10)
                    timeMinutes.Text = "0" + minutes.ToString();
                else
                    timeMinutes.Text = minutes.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                timeMinutes.Text = "00";
            }
            if (seconds <= 59 && seconds>=0)
            {
                seconds--;
                if (seconds < 10)
                    timeSeconds.Text = "0" + seconds.ToString();
                else
                    timeSeconds.Text = seconds.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                timeSeconds.Text = "00";
            }
        }

    }
```

Эту функцию я вызываю в событии 
`private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartTimer();
        }`
Для справки заношу 30 минут и 00 секунд. Labl'ы имеют вид: 29:0-1. Да и ход вычитания не показывается

Comment: ничего не понятно, что считается, как и зачем и причем тут таймер вообще?

Comment: @tym32167 мне нужно реализовать отсчет таймера. Т.к. никаких функций в c# я не нашел, я написал сам. И что вам не понятно? timeSeconds.Text это label с секундами,timeMinutes.Text это минуты.

Comment: Возьмите листок бумаги и карандаш и выполните действия Вашего кода на бумаге. Сообщите нам о результатах.

Comment: @Igor вы по существу ничего тоже не сказали. Мимо бы прошли

Comment: Я не могу пройти мимо. Мир и так уже катится в тартарары.

Comment: чтобы реализовать отсчет таймера нужен только настроенный таймер. Для представления даты и времени есть тип `DateTime`. Для представления интервала времени есть `TimeSpan`. Что вы в коде делаете я не понимаю, но не вижу там ни настройки таймера, и засечения времени\интервалов времени

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант кода:

```
    private int seconds;
    private int minutes;
    private TimeSpan time1;


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        minutes = 30;
        seconds = 0;
        time1 = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        timer2.Enabled = true;
        timer2.Start();
    }



    public  void StartTimer()//Функция запуска отсчета таймера
    {

        if (timer2.Enabled)
        {

            if (time1.TotalSeconds > 0)
            {
                time1 = time1.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            }
            timeMinutes.Text = time1.Minutes.ToString("##");
            timeSeconds.Text = time1.Seconds.ToString("##");
        }

    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartTimer();
    }
```

[image: Работа примера]

Кстати вот пара ссылок которые могут быть Вам полезны.

[1.Работа с датой и временем](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/19.1.php)

[2.Форматирование строк](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/7.5.php)